# Difference between unit type and 'a in ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

What's the difference between `unit -> unit` and `'a -> 'a` in OCaml?

For example:

```
# let f g a = if (g a > a) then a ;;
val f : (unit -> unit) -> unit -> unit = <fun>

# let f g a = if (g a > a ) then a else a;;
val f : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

Why does the first one give `unit -> unit` and the second `'a -> 'a`?

Comment: tldr: unit is the type used when nothing is return by a function and `'a` a type variable meaning any type including `unit`. So where the `'a` your function can take a value of any type e.g. `"abc"` can go there e.g. in the first location for `'a -> int`. The function will return an it btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` expression in the first variant has no `else` clause, so the true branch of the `if` expression must have type `unit`.  This means that the type of `a` must be `unit` as well, and `g` must have type `unit -> unit`.

In the second variant, due to the `else` clause, the only requirement is that the true and false branches of the `if` expression have the same type, so the type generalizes, and so does the type of `g`.

Comment: The unit type is a type which has only one value, written `()`. If you write `if c then a`, there is an implicit `else ()` branch.

Comment: @AhmedBaoun it might help to think of the unit type as a void type

Answer (score 11):

Note that in OCaml, `if` is an expression: it returns a value.

The key to understand your problem is that

```
if condition then a
```

is equivalent to

```
if condition then a else ()
```

The typing rules for `if` are the following:

- the condition should have type `bool`
- both branches should have the same type
- the whole if expression has the same type as the branches

In other words, in `if cond then a`, `a` should have type `unit`.

Answer (score 8):

`unit` is the type used when nothing is return by a function (basically, functions who are printing things)

`'a` is a neutral type. It is a placeholder for any type.

Comment: Unit type is a strange concept at the beginning. Personally I translate it as « side effect », if a function have data from a side effect at the input I add a unit type parameter, if there is a side effect for the output I return the unit value from the unit type. This is a way to document your code With a « warning side effect area ».